# Wagtail: Filtering a search on a ManyToMany through model

Tags: django, wagtail

In a [Wagtail](https://wagtail.io)-based site, I have an `ArticlePage` model which is related to an `Author` snippet model in a many-to-many relationship like this:

```
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.core.models import Orderable, Page
from wagtail.search import index
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

class ArticlePage(Page):
    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
       index.FilterField('author_id'),
    ]

@register_snippet
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

class ArticleAuthorRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles')
    page = ParentalKey('ArticlePage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='authors')
```

I want to be able to search `ArticlePage`s *and* filter them by a particular `Author`, which I can do like this:

```
author = Author.objects.get(id=1)

articles = ArticlePage.objects.live() \
                              .filter(authors__author=author) \
                              .search('football')
```

*But* in the dev server logs I get this warning:

> articles.ArticlePage: ArticlePage.search_fields contains non-existent field ‘author_id’

My question is: **Am I doing this right?** It works, but the warning makes me think there might be a more correct way to achieve the same result.

I have also tried using `FilterField('authors')`, which stops the warning, but I can't work out how to filter on that.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet.. but have you tried: `index.FilterField('articles__name')`?

Comment: I assume you mean `authors__name`? But no, `articles__name`, `authors__name`, `authors__id`, `author__name` and `author__id` all generate the same warning.

Comment: `ArticlePage.objects.live().filter(author__name='Phil')`, author (the field name) not authors.

Comment: Thanks @allcaps but filtering a QuerySet isn't the same thing as adding Wagtail `search_fields`.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way was explained in the [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.1/topics/search/indexing.html#index-relatedfields)

here an example that is shared in the official documentation:

```py
from wagtail.search import index

class Book(models.Model, index.Indexed):
    ...

    search_fields = [
        index.SearchField('title'),
        index.FilterField('published_date'),

        index.RelatedFields('author', [
            index.SearchField('name'),
            index.FilterField('date_of_birth'),
        ]),
    ]
```

so in your case, you should write:

```py
class ArticlePage(Page):
    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
       index.RelatedFields(
            "author", [index.SearchField("id")]
        ),
    ]
```

let me know if it is working

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this, but unfortunately I get a similar warning: `articles.ArticlePage: ArticlePage.search_fields contains non-existent field 'author'`

Comment: sorry for not updating my answer,  the indexing of additional fields is not supported on the DB backend here the documentation: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.1/topics/search/indexing.html#indexing-extra-fields

there is a workaround, that you create a `new field` in your model and in the `save` method you save the foreign_key as a string in this new field
then you do your search on that new field, (I used this little workaround to be able to search without changing my DataBase)

Comment: I'm using the PostgreSQL backend.

Comment: I'm interested on the solution also

Comment: I wrote the solution that I used, did it work for you? @balsagoth